# How to move a range from three separate ranges into one

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset in a worksheet

```
A1 | Cost | B1 | Cost | C1| Cost
A2 | Cost | B2 | Cost | C2| Cost
...
```

I would like to move these to one column like so:

```
A1 | Cost
B1 | Cost
C1 | Cost
A2 | Cost
B2 | Cost
...
```

I have looked around but I am not really good at VBA, which is what I assume would be best to use.  I have to do that 100+ times and the tables are large, and will likely have to replicate it often enough that making something would be useful and save me days of work.

Not sure really where to start.   I tried the macro recording but the paste offset overwrites the previous paste because the row offset is on the current row not the last row of the destination.

Here is a sample of my dataset. Trying to get from Blue to Yellow - or take one set from each column set add to Yellow column set then next row and repeat till there is no more in the first column set

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThDZm.png)

Comment: Please provide any code you've tried thusfar.  StackOverflow is a collaborative site for helping with *specific* coding issues, not a code for you service.  If you simply need help getting started, please use the *Macro Recorder* within the Developer tab of Excel.

Comment: @Cyril That is not correct. Having an existing failed attempt is not a requirement for asking questions on Stack Overflow. It is only a requirement for debugging/"why isn't this code working" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I interpreted your question:

I put the following formula in H2:

```
=INDEX(dataset,TRUNC((ROW(H2)-ROW($H$2))*2/COLUMNS(dataset))+1,MOD((ROW(H2)-ROW($H$2))*2,COLUMNS(dataset))+1)
```

and this in I2:

```
=INDEX(dataset,TRUNC((ROW(I2)-ROW($I$2))*2/COLUMNS(dataset))+1,MOD((ROW(I2)-ROW($I$2))*2,COLUMNS(dataset))+1+1)
```

with the range "dataset" assigned to the rows that contained your data.

Copying them down the rows gave me this:

[image: Sample Data]

I wish I had noticed your sample data earlier.  What I did was extend the dataset range to one column beyond the earlier range so that it had 9 columns (I probably could have added one to the actual range, but I was being lazy).  I modified the formulas slightly to account for the empty column as follows:

In K2:

```
=INDEX(dataset,TRUNC((ROW(K2)-ROW($K$2))*3/COLUMNS(dataset))+1,MOD((ROW(K2)-ROW($K$2))*3,COLUMNS(dataset))+1)
```

In L2:

```
=INDEX(dataset,TRUNC((ROW(L2)-ROW($L$2))*3/COLUMNS(dataset))+1,MOD((ROW(L2)-ROW($L$2))*3,COLUMNS(dataset))+1+1)
```

In this version, the range "dataset" is:  $A$3:$I$8

This, the revised picture looks like this:
[image]

Comment: This works quite well for what I need.  I wouldn't have even thought of that.  Would you be willing to walk through it and explain it? Not really familiar with how ROW works, though I will be looking it up now.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  You saved me days of work

Comment: Sure. last time I included an explanation in an answer, it was deleted. What I did was this: The TRUNC((ROW(U2)-ROW($U$2)) piece is counting from first row of that set (which was $U$2 to the current row which starts at U2 and increments it for each row. I use MOD to break these up either by rows or by columns. This way it resets at the last row to start counting columns again or at the last column to start counting rows again. The 3 multiplier in the new set (and the 2 multiplier in the earlier set) adjust these so that the columns are grouped into 3 (or 2) columns.

Comment: Not sure why you added a column but let me play around with it.  Thank again for the help

Comment: Originally, I saw the 6 columns in the message and set it to 6, but then I saw the 8 columns in the linked image file and realized that my formula did not account for the extra columns in between.  Because I was being lazy, I adjusted it to use 9 columns (three sets of 3) even though there were only 8.  I could have added 1 to the denominator, but have been working on quite a few other efforts, so I was being lazy by just assuming there is a blank column to the right of the data rather than fix my formula.

Answer (score 1):

In **E1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$2,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0),MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3)+1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

If you have data down to **C100**, then replace the **$C$2** in the formula with the correct value.

Comment: [link]https://imgur.com/a/gyx6aDU    The Blue is what I have the yellow is what I am trying to get to.